# View Model - Struct or Class?

Tags: ios, mvvm, swift2

Would it be a good idea to have view model as a struct instead of a class in iOS MVVM architecture?

Comment: That entirely depends on how you are intending to use it.  Structs have their place in programming, as do classes.  I would lean toward the View Model being a class because often times you are going to want to have methods inside the view model, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Putz1103 I can have methods inside swift struct as well so that is not a problem. However, often time underlying model does change and as a result view model has to be mutated/recreated if it's a struct. In that case, class makes more sense as I won't have to reassign view model every time underlying model changes. Just wanted to see if anyone has tried implementing view model as a struct and if there were any pros of doing that